# How are devices handled with Citrix XenApp?

Tags: usb, citrix, thin-client

We have an application which interacts with a USB interactive whiteboard.

A customer recently asked if our software would work with XenApp 6.

I am sure our application will, however the hardware is unknown since I don't know how the client side would handle the USB device.

Last time I used Citrix was over 10 years ago with Citrix MetaFrame and back then only a limited support for usb devices was available.  Has the situation improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citrix USB support has greatly expanded since your last interactiont w/ Citrix. You would need enable this via policy within Citrix (or the gpedit plugin w/ Citrix, which is recommended), but you should be good.

All that said, with a unique product like that, compared to a simple device such as keyobard, testing would be ideal.

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX816193

Answer (score 0):

the Device Support in Citrix Xen App is much better then before. If you use the actual openFile Dialog you can access to all Devices you publish over XenApp. But if you use an old openFile Dialog (like the open Key Dialog in StarMoney) you can't access to the published Devices.

Regards
Rene